# Set Default Value 1 to an EntityName (Status) in Entity Framework database-first approach

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0, I have set default value for the `Status` column to 1 in my back-end database. But while inserting a new record, it generates 0 by default for the `status` column. I want `1` as by default value which is set in database, but Entity Framework is changing it to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You have to open the `edmx` file and select the `Status` property from the corresponding entity. Then press `F4` to show the `Property-View`. There you have to select `Identity` for `StoreGeneratedPattern`. `Itentity` means that the database generates the value on `INSERT` but not on `UPDATE`.

Comment: {"Modifying a column with the 'Identity' pattern is not supported. Column: 'Status'. Table: 'lamiModel.Store.finish'."}

This is What i'm Getting as Exception when i try to upate a storedGenaratedPattern= Identity . Your trick is  not working

Comment: I thought that the column is readonly and set by the database only.

Comment: its was inerting 1 but when updating it to 0, so i got exception

Answer (score 0):

Setting the default in the database is useful if you are inserting records in ways other than through Entity Framework, or if you are creating a new non-null column on a table that already contains records. 
In Code First, you can specify the database default in a migration:

```
public override void Up()
{    
   AddColumn("dbo.Foos", "Status", c => c.Integer(nullable: false, defaultValue: 1));
}
```

C# sets integers to zero by default and that is why Entity Framework is overwriting the database.

Therefore you will also have to set the default value in your entity class if it is not the default for that type :

```
//partial is only necessary in Database First
public partial class Foo
{
   private int _Status = 1;

   public int Status
   {
      get{ return _Status; }
      set{ _Status = value; }
   }
}
```

...or if you prefer constructor initialisation:

```
public partial class Foo
{
   public Foo()
   {
      Status = 1;
   }

   public int Status { get; set; }
}
```

...and, if you are using C# 6.0:

```
public partial class Foo
{
   public int Status { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

Comment: if i has to write 7 to 10 lines of code just to set default value why should i not  just insert obj.Status=1; that serves the purpose

Comment: In order for that to be a default, you should put that line in the constructor. Constructor initialisation vs backing field initialisation is up to you. Refactoring tools in my IDE make creating backing fields very straightforward